# jQuery can't get element added by jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I added the following table row using jQuery AJAX:

```
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" id="increment"></button>
</td>
```

The problem is that I can't match this created button after this:

```
$("#increment").click(function () {
    console.log("Clicked!");
})
```

I tried the live() function but seems to be deprecated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').on('click', "#increment", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
})
```